# "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" after upgrade from 18.04 to 19.10

Tags: networking, dell, 19.10

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. I'm using a Dell XPS 13" 7390 that shipped with 18.04 already installed. Upgraded from 18.04 to 19.10 through the GUI prompt, and after rebooting I no longer have Wi-Fi.

Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
55:02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
56: Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1653]
57- Kernel modules: iwlwifi
58-03:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02)
59- Kernel driver in use: pcieport
```

And this is the output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

I also tried disabling 802.11n, but that didn't help.

Any help is appreciated!

Edits, with additional commands tried:

`sudo modprobe iwlwifi` fails with the message `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Exec format error`. Adding the `--force` flag doesn't change that.

`uname -r` (this is the Linux kernel version, right?) outputs/returns `4.15.0-1081-oem`.

`modinfo iwlwifi | grep filename` prints `filename:     /lib/modules/4.15.0-1081-oem/updates/dkms/iwlwifi.ko`.

`sudo dpkg -s backport-iwlwifi-dkms` outputs this:

```
Package: backport-iwlwifi-dkms
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: kernel
Installed-Size: 9599
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 7906-0ubuntu4
Provides: iwlwifi-modules
Depends: dkms (>= 2.1.0.0), libc6-dev | libc-dev
Description: iwlwifi driver backport in DKMS format
 Intel works with periodic releases of the iwlwifi driver that are
 tested with a specific combination of components such as firmware and
 hostap. These releases can be seen as snapshots of the development
 trees (including upstream) that can be used on older kernels.
 .
 This package provides iwlwifi modules built from iwlwifi-public
 defconfig based on upstream master branch.
Original-Maintainer: You-Sheng Yang <vicamo@gmail.com>
Homepage: https://gitlab.com/vicamo/backport-iwlwifi-dkms
Modaliases: cfg80211(net-pf-16-proto-16-family-nl80211), iwlwifi(pci:v00008086d00007AF0sv*sd00000A10bc*sc*i*,
```

The `Modaliases:` stuff continues for quite a while (total file size was around 32kb).

`dmesg | grep iwl` doesn't print anything either.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Updated. `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` fails.

Comment: Very interesting! Please also show, in an edit, `uname -r` as well as: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep filename`

Comment: Thanks! I've added what the laptop prints out from both of those comments.

Comment: Can you insert the module via "modprobe --force iwlwifi " ? and have you tried installing the backport-iwlwifi-dkms package ?

Comment: Please also show us: `sudo dpkg -s backport-iwlwifi-dkms` I suspect that it is installed and that we should remove it.

Comment: @chili555 It appears this is correct, yes. I don't know as much about the full output as you do but `dpkg -s backport-iwlwifi-dkms` says that it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try removing the backport package.

```
sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Reboot.

Any improvement?

Comment: After removing the package and rebooting, the settings still report that there's no wi-fi adapter.

Comment: Please show us: `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: No output; added this to the question.

Comment: How about: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and then: `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: That `grep` also gives nothing, even with `--force` added for `modprobe`.

Comment: Please run: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 2723` If it comes back blank, then: `sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms` Reboot and show us: `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108690/discussion-between-eric-fulmer-and-chili555).